# Best practice to catch last render in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding a situation I am currently having.  While I have found a workaround, I don't think it's the best practice.  First thing my component does is make an API get call and send the results to the this.props.  Following that I have a conditional check based on those props.  Here's the problem, the component renders multiple times (4), and the prop being called is a prop from a previous state.  So I have to wait for the second render before continuing.  Here is a layout of my workaround.

```
import React from 'react'

class TestComponent extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
      api = this.make.apiCall()
         }
    render(){
        let something = null
        console.log('Render Test Comp')

        if(this.props){
            something = (
                <div>this.props Exsists</div>
            )
        }

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            {something}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default TestComponent
```

So basically what I want to know is, was the best possible method to catch the LAST render of a page?  Is my method above ok?  Is there a better way?  Should I throw the conditional statement inline the JSX(which I think is so ugly and confusing if you have nested conditional statements inside your JSX)?  You guys all rock, and have always answered my questions that are much more specific.  This one should be easy ;)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Code also, what is api for?

Comment: Basically my question is what is the best possible way to grab the last possible render.  The api call is based on params coming in, in this instance for a user.  This is in regards to a user detail view.  When switching from one user to the next on this, the previous user would show on the first render.  So I needed to make a workaround

Comment: To avoid rendering previous user data, you can clear user data before new api call.

Comment: How do you clear the data?  Is this done on componentUnmount?

Comment: If I understand your case, you could hold user data in state. Set data to none, call api, save api result to state. And do that before each api call (user change).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question here, because the code is wrong in many ways. Plus your code snippet does not make sense with the explanation.

**Problem 1:**

```js
api = this.make.apiCall()
```

- Where is `this.make.apiCal()`? What response is expected?
- `api` should be a state from what I see. In order to rerender your component because of change got from api call.

**Problem 2:**

```js
if(this.props){
  something = (
     <div>this.props Exsists</div>
  )
}
```

- This is absolutely wrong because this case will always be triggered. `this.props` is `{}` i.e. empty object which is truthy value.

See the Pen 
  [Hello World in React](https://codepen.io/tolsee/pen/YBawdG/) by Tulsi Sapkota ([@tolsee](https://codepen.io/tolsee))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: I'm sorry.  I worded that question poorly.  What I mean to ask.

Comment: When making an API call, when is the best time to check the res.data for a condition?  During render() or inline with JSX?